# Statıstıc problem

Tags: calculus, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

[image][image]

Will I use binomial distribution for this question? Can you help me please thnk you

Comment: Yes, you should use the binominal distribution. What are your ideas ?

Comment: My sollutıon is correct or not? @calculus

Comment: Your solution is correct. :)

Comment: :) thnk you @calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct!

$p^m (1-p)^{n-m}$ is the probability of winning $m$ out of $n$ games in a specific order, ie. e.g. win, then lose, then lose, then win, then win... To get the probability for any order you multiply by ${n \choose m}$ which is exactly what you have done.

Comment: Thnk you :) @jolle